# Powershell scripting quote issue

Tags: powershell

I am running a powershell script below. Notice that the parameter inside GetProxy() is inside single quotes. If I use double quotes instead of single quote the script does not run.
SO this works

```
c:\>powershell.exe  IEX(Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/example.html -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials  -Proxy $([System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy('http://example.com/').Absoluteuri))
```

This does not work

```
c:\>powershell.exe  IEX(Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/example.html -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials  -Proxy $([System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy("http://example.com/").Absoluteuri))
```

Does somebody know how to run this script without using single quotes inside GeProxy()?.

Note that i can not run this inside a ps1 script. It has to be executed inline as in above snippet.

Comment: Why can't you use single quote?
If this is because you are running in command prompt so you can just surround the whole line with double quotes (start right after the `powershell.exe` command) and then put single quotes inside the line just like you did in the example that does work:
`powershell.exe "IEX(Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/example.html -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials  -Proxy $([System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy('http://example.com/').Absoluteuri))"`

Comment: Thanks but this does not help. I just can not use single quotes.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you can't use single quotes? This kinda looks like an typical XY-Problem (http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Powershell can run Base64 -encoded commands. It's quite useful to get around weird quoting issues and whatnot. But I'll second @Paxz: what is the reason single quotes can't be used?

Answer (score 0):

Just like @vonPryz said, you can try to encode your working command with the single quote into Base64 and then run `powershell.exe` with the encoded string, first run this in powershell:

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("'IEX(Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/example.html -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials  -Proxy $([System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy('http://example.com/').Absoluteuri))'"))
```

Then take to output and run this from cmd:

```
powershell.exe -encodedCommand JwBJAEUAWAAoAEkAbgB2AG8AawBlAC0AVwBlAGIAUgBlAHEAdQBlAHMAdAAgAGgAdAB0AHAAOgAvAC8AZQB4AGEAbQBwAGwAZQAuAGMAbwBtAC8AZQB4AGEAbQBwAGwAZQAuAGgAdABtAGwAIAAtAFAAcgBvAHgAeQBVAHMAZQBEAGUAZgBhAHUAbAB0AEMAcgBlAGQAZQBuAHQAaQBhAGwAcwAgACAALQBQAHIAbwB4AHkAIABoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAGUAeABhAG0AcABsAGUALgBjAG8AbQAvACkAJwA=
```